# Setting Default Applications that are NOT standard or available in drop-down menu

Tags: applications, default

Does anyone know how to set a default application that does not appear in the drop-down menu? I use Guayadeque as my music player but it does not appear as an option in the drop-down menu?[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHMIg.jpgimage]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if your app isn't shown in one of these drop-downs, it means that the app hasn't been properly registered in your system. You have to register your app in the system and create a `[your-app-name].desktop` file (those usually reside in `/usr/share/applications` or `/local/share/applications` directories).

A .desktop file is actually a text file, so you can open and edit it in any text editor. Among other things, a .desktop file should contain a `Categories` line, which states the category of the app (one or several), which helps the system to properly categorize the app. For instance, for a music player this line usually looks like this:

```
Categories=Audio;Music;Player;
```

If Guayadeque already has a .desktop file, please check if it contains the `Categories` line.

On how to register apps and create .desktop files in Ubuntu you can refer to [this tutorial](https://itsfoss.com/add-application-list-open-applications-ubuntu-1310/).

Answer (score 0):

In the elementary os AppCenter, there are two apps (i have installed) that can do that. They are: **AppEditor** and **Menu editor**. I recommend AppEditor over Menu Editor, because it lets you change app icons and the like. To give it the icon in the menu, turn on the `show hidden entries` button. then, in the `search bar`, `search` for the app.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqkLv.png]
[image]

Don't forget to make sure it has the proper category though (music player) or you will have to edit the desktop file.